# Beginner, how do I add CSS in a different file than the HTML file?

Tags: html, css, web

Bit of a noob, but I'll stab.

I have used SoloLearn for most of my coding, so the CSS is a tab embedded into the file, and we can't see it. So.. how do I name a css file, and how do I point it to a html file in the same folder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Create a file called styles.css

Import the file in the head of your html document with

```
<head>
   <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <title>Title</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

To connect your CSS file to a HTML one you can use this sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

So you are pointing a CSS file in HTML by this line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

in `head`

Answer (score 1):

You can call it whatever you want, but you include a link to it in your HTML, rather than point it at the HTML. If you called it "style.css" your HTML would start like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```